# What is the difference between set() and update() method in Svelte Store?

Tags: svelte, svelte-store

I'm new to Svelte Store. [Here in svelte tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/writable-stores), they used `update()` method in `<Incrementer/>` and `<Decrementer/>` components to update value. But in `<Resetter/>`, they used `set()` method to reset value. What exactly is the difference between `update()` and `set()` method in svelte store?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

From the [docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store-writable):

> `set` is a method that takes one argument which is the value to be set. The store value gets set to the value of the argument if the store value is not already equal to it.
>
> `update` is a method that takes one argument which is a callback. The callback takes the existing store value as its argument and returns the new value to be set to the store.

So you can use `update` if the next value should be dependent on the current value.

Also: `update` only exists for convenience and is *not* part of the "store contract":

- A readable store only requires the `subscribe` method
- A writable store requires the `set` method

Component code like `$store = value` uses `set` internally.

Comment: `So you can use update if the next value should be dependent on the current value` => this line answers my question. Thanks.

Comment: But then you could use update in every case, why set() even exists?

Comment: @Knemay `set` is simpler than `update`, you do not need to pass a function.

Comment: this help me understands set and update. Basically they are the same, use as you like haha