# How do I share date context with multiple components in Svelte

Tags: svelte, store

I need to share a date from a component in Svelte to several different components which are not children of the component. If they were all children I think I would use 'setContext' and 'getContext'. The best way I have come across is using a store, however when I use the store it does not appear to be saving a 'Date' but a 'Writable'. When I try to get values from the date it will not let me.

store.ts

```js
import {writable} from "svelte/store"

export const date = writable<Date>(new Date())
```

component.ts

```js
import { date } from "./store";
var hour = date.getHours();
let calendarDate = date.toISOString().split('T')[0]
```

I get an error "Property 'getHours' does not exist on type 'Writable'" and
"Property 'toISOString' does not exist on type 'Writable'"

Is there a way to fix this or a better way to pass a date from one component to multiple using state, context, or something else I'm not aware of?

I tried using a store to save the date and was expecting the ability to be able to view and update the date in other components.

Answer (score 0):

You only need the store if you want to update components reactively. If you do not need that feature, you can just not use a store.

To read the store value only once you can use the [`get`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store-get) function from `'svelte/store'`. To change the value or update it, you can use the [functions on the store](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store-writable) itself (`set`/`update`, differences are [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71091343/546730)).

```js
import { date } from "./store";
import { get } from 'svelte/store';

const $date = get(date);
var hour = $date.getHours();
let calendarDate = $date.toISOString().split('T')[0]
```

In a component one can use special [$-syntax](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-4-prefix-stores-with-$-to-access-their-values) to read and write stores more conveniently.

Comment: I believe it does need to be reactive. In component.ts I am setting a date which will then need to be saved in the store so it can be used by another component on the page. I will end up using it in a fetch call, but for now I am just trying to pass it to the component.

Comment: Usage is completely independent from reactivity. You have a global variable that can read and written anywhere, the only difference would be that the a Svelte component would know *when* the variable is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. I was able to fix the problem with your help and looking through the docs again. Here is what I did to fix it.
In component1.svelte I was able to import and reference it using the $ syntax. I was also able to set the date. In component2.svelte I just needed to subscribe to the data.

component1.svelte

```
<script>
    import { dateStore } from "./store";    
    let date = $dateStore;
    var hour = date.getHours();
    let calendarDate = date.toISOString().split('T')[0]

    const handleGo = () => {
        let temp = new Date(calendarDate)
        selectedDate = temp.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);
        dateStore.set(temp)
    };
</script>
```

componenet2.svelte

```
<script>
    import { dateStore } from '../../../lib/store';
    
    let date;
    dateStore.subscribe((val) => date = val)
    
    
</script>


<h1>{date}</h1>
```

Comment: This is not a forum, do *not* use answers to "respond" to people, it's not how this site works. Also, there is no need to use `subscribe` in components, use [reactive statements](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-3-$-marks-a-statement-as-reactive) or the store directly, that way subscriptions are cleaned up again when the component is removed. Not doing so leads to memory leaks.

Comment: `dateStore.set(temp)` is just `$dateStore = temp` and the entire second component is just `<h1>{$dateStore}</h1>` with nothing else but the import.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I was able to change those to the reactive components as suggested. I did not finish the second component in my example, I just put the reference in an <h1> so I could easily see the value changed. I am going to use the date for a fetch call.